# For all entries in one table, add to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-insert

Database looks like this:

table1

```
id   | name
1    | James
2    | Rick
3    | Carl
```

table2

```
id   | age | gender
<this table is empty>
```

I want to make a query that passes the same data for all ID's into table2. So after the query the database would look like the following:

table1

```
id   | name
1    | James
2    | Rick
3    | Carl
```

table2

```
id   | age | gender
1    | 20  | male
2    | 20  | male
3    | 20  | male
```

I've tried to make some INNER JOIN queries, but I can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whence is the source of data for age = 20 and gender = male?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was just making a random example. I need the values to be fixed and in reality it has nothing to do with this database structure, it was just the easiest way for me to illustrate what I wanted to do. Answers were on point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
insert into table2 (id, age, gender)
    select id, 20, 'male'
    from table1;
```

Normally, `id`s are defined automatically, so you can probably leave that out:

```
insert into table2 (age, gender)
    select 20, 'male'
    from table1;
```

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `id`s from `table1`, and then fixed values for other columns.

If so, consider the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
insert into table2 (id, age, gender)
select id, 20, 'male' from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like described here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

could be something like

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, age, gender)
SELECT id,
       20,
       'male'
FROM table1
WHERE 1 = 1;
```